# How do I filter a message's content through a program, then forward it to another address?

Tags: exim

In qmail, you could put this in a .forward file:

```
|/usr/local/bin/myfilter | forward upstream@example.com
```

This would pipe the whole message, incl. headers, to the `myfilter` program, then forward the message printed to its standard output to upstream@example.com.

However, Exim doesn't have a `forward` program, and generally ignores the output of pipe transports.

How can one do this with Exim .forward files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipe the program output through `sendmail`. Exim installs its own implementation of the program.

```
|sh -c '/usr/local/bin/myfilter | /usr/sbin/sendmail -i upstream@example.com'
```

Notes:

- You have to use `sh` - Exim will execute the indicated program directly, rather than through a shell like qmail. A shell is needed to parse the `|` operator.
- Specify the full path to `sendmail`, as `/usr/sbin/` likely won't be in the `PATH` of the user that Exim will be running under while processing the `.forward` file.
- Don't use the `-t` sendmail flag.